# LLDB Failed to connect port.Under Vmware, CentOS, Android Studio

Tags: vmware, debugging

I am trying to debug JNI code in Android Studio which runs under VM Workstartion + CentOS 7.  The error message is:

```
Failed to connect port
com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriverException: 
Failed to connect port
    at   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver$ThrowIfNotValid.throwIfNeeded(LLDBDriver.java:143)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.connectPlatform(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:308)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForLaunch(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:158)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForAttach(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:199)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.prepareTarget(AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.java:98)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeDebugProcess.doStart(AndroidNativeDebugProcess.java:113)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$3.run(CidrDebugProcess.java:307)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:724)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:714)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$0(QueueProcessor.java:106)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$wrappingProcessor$1(QueueProcessor.java:106)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$2(QueueProcessor.java:203)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$startProcessing$3(QueueProcessor.java:203)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can run the debugger on a different machine without VMware and it works fine.
I think it has something to do with port remapping.  Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: is your VM's network connection set to a NAT or Bridged Connection?

Comment: Bridged........

Comment: Bridged make the VM OS have direct access to the NIC, I don't think its the NIC. what does the config file look like? is the selected port being used by another service? `netstat -l` maybe there is a conflict somewhere on the VM.